# Return only the vowels in a list of strings

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I have to write the `onlyVowels :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]` function that should only return the vowels.

For example: `onlyVowels ["Return", "Only", "Vowels", "Please"] == ["eu", "Oy", "oe", "eae"]`

So far, I have come up with this:

```
onlyVowels x = filter (isAVowel x) x where
  isAVowel x = elem x "aeiouyAEIOUY"
```

The problem with this is the fact that I have to check a list of words, not just a character. This exercise also prohibits the use of recursion.

Comment: Have you learned of `map` already?

Comment: Hint: write `onlyV :: [Char] -> [Char]` first, operating on a single string. Once you solved that, you can think on how to extend that to a list-of-strings.

Comment: The biggest challenge by far will be determining which characters are "vowels". This is tricky enough in English (is "y" a vowel?), but when you consider other languages it becomes much harder. And since several languages can use the same characters, I'd just call it impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```hs
onlyVowels :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
onlyVowels = map (filter isAVowel) where
  isAVowel x = x `elem` "aeiouyAEIOUY"
```

Use [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to apply your filtering function to each string in the list of strings. Also note that this is eta reduced. It is the same as writing:

```hs
onlyVowels xs = map (filter isAVowel) xs where...
```

Using [`toLower`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:toLower) from `Data.Char` may also be a good idea. Then you can filter only on "aeiouy", like the following:

```hs
import Data.Char (toLower)

onlyVowels :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
onlyVowels = map (filter isAVowel) where
  isAVowel x = toLower x `elem` "aeiouy"
```